# strange value after updating database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

in my app I want to display the values of my database at a TextView.
But after updating my database (method "change") I got some strange code in the TextView instead of a normal value.
Here my code:

```
newPreis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPreis);
newHerkunft = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextHerkunft);

public void changeDatabase(View view) {
    String pNeu = newPreis.toString();
    String hNeu = newHerkunft.toString();
    db.execSQL("UPDATE DATEN SET preis='"+pNeu+"' WHERE _id=1");
    db.execSQL("UPDATE DATEN SET herkunft='"+hNeu+"' WHERE _id=1");
}

// anzeigeApfel is a TextView

if(pApfel.moveToFirst() && hApfel.moveToFirst()) {
   String prApfel = pApfel.getString(pApfel.getColumnIndex("preis"));
   String herApfel = hApfel.getString(hApfel.getColumnIndex("herkunft"));
   anzeigeApfel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   anzeigeApfel.setText("" + prApfel + "\n" + herApfel);
}
```

Comment: can you please add more details on what the error is and what did you expect from your code? Also provide a complete working example. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Comment: *I got some strange code in the TextView* is absolutely useless as a problem description, as we have no idea what *strange code* might mean. What **specific** problem are you having?

Comment: If you got some unexpected value in your TextView, don't you think that including the value in your question is somewhat pertinent?

Comment: At least you should probably change `newPreis.toString()` to `newPreis.getText().toString()` and the same for `newHerkunft`, if these are `EditText` instances. Also, learn to use prepared statements instead of string concatenated parameters with `execSQL()`.

Comment: You are setting yourself up for SQL injection attacks by creating SQL by concatenation of strings to build the query. Always use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

The *Strange code* is because you are using the `EditText`'s `toString` method as opposed to retrieving the value held by the `EditText`.

You get the value held by the `EditText` by using the `getText` method which then needs to be converted to a `String` using the `Text`'s toString method.

So instead of :-

```
    String pNeu = newPreis.toString();
    String hNeu = newHerkunft.toString();
```

You should use :-

```
    String pNeu = newPreis.getText().toString();
    String hNeu = newHerkunft.getText().toString();
```